# Sphinx 2.3.1-beta where is search binary?

Tags: sphinx

Having just built Sphinx from source, cannot find the CLI search tool 'search'.

Everything else is in place! IE, config set up, searchd runs AOK...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLI search tool was removed from Sphinx in version 2.2.2.

For testing purposes you can now use mysql client and SphinxQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, we avoid MySQL like The Black Death(!) - but have been testing with the python API. Great stuff! Will look for the PostgreSQL analog of the SpinxQL approach. Thanks again!

Comment: There is no PostgreSQL analog for SphinxQL as SphinxQL uses the MySQL protocol (4.1). To be clear: you don't need the whole MySQL Server, only a MySQL client/connector. So you could use MySQL-Python library to connect to Sphinx.